# Meaning of "Two can play this game"

Tags: expressions

What is the meaning of the expression *two can play this game* ? I have often heard it as a reply to a statement. When and in what context is it used ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the definition [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/two-can-play-at-that-game)

> **Two can play at that game**: something that you say when you intend to harm someone in the same way as they harmed you:
>
> *When I found out that my husband had been having an affair, I thought "two can play at that game!"*

Answer (score 5):

If Person A is playing tricks/mind games, Person B's response is:

> Two can play that game

meaning that B will use A's tricks against them.

Comment: Is it something like *tit for tat* ?

Comment: That's fairly similar, yes.

Comment: "retaliation in kind" from [Tit for Tat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tit_for_tat), very similar